# Webservice is giving error 401 in Android Retrofit 2, but works in Volley and Postman

Tags: android, kotlin, authorization, retrofit2

I have been using retrofit and auth for a while with no problem.
But from this API call while everything is exactly the same as my other projects which works, I'm constantly getting error code 401

here is my API calling code:

```
@GET("workers")
    fun getWorkersList(): Observable<BaseResponseModel<WorkerAttributes>>

    companion object Factory {
        fun create(): WebServices {
            val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAiLCJraWQiOiIzaGltWWEyYmJHS18zSVdZMUxUUHdyTUl2ZkF3ZVhZQmRNLTU5XzN6c0MwIn0.DIwk0Q215_M7rt3iGfyRVrImhKCXvEB5NBoLQj6iqBnN9yCWWBhGW9fmX6beOajtWgC8gpupe1hJ-iurFRbo2Eg52Nh9ljkkO5Mz8ulSpH7YlfP8Yi-TBrNoPIf_IvHrr1Rt8bG0w2Ie1Jo3BBOguMQ6Q2WI4fQDY-oFIluxOQ5t9E0_XvDhna7maiQnWevLbu80Mj7g643v5nvNWOdpSAXW91rZXIXdal_A_ffY-IUyvYhEJuOkyHWwNonuGjiGHWKPTjTR16w3seoSs4srkacOIN1cmMdXKlkvlWSYCv5Nd8xJ_rTqA4GIyKLRSALYcuiTFMOIxeMIpPB5DjpMTOmOD72QnD8MHMx-SNHk2Yva5iPs__h_WXIKzjME6wRQxTBayfWcXuA6loTdSXnV5Tfl63y62nYZUesh2ElcF5ZK_if3R70jTh-_dxAc8-EcxagAgeCAYNGx-i0fokA4Crfz0A9MKJv5XKn8hY-_4_AT-tsIwBQ6YWYISPBGqyUFoBX0LGDEojIywQBXcLSqHRoah45IDW87TTjVTtPjKsxrIr9rl661dYKRE4ViTLGON0hRBmmNAOokcTNv4tEPBWDS5OPIVtnqkCruAV1YXGKMWpbGOlH6pi2sLY5FtNP9h7nNKnK59gX_FMwXyLjzdPU7HkEEv2svTHN_vBFDUeE.UmwA_rn0FGSRXl4kVPrF3Q.lpZ6JQSke2wLCi3X18mNMAYs5x2nCk7LGrs65nOo-cv8FQ1zfYz9qj7TdH26BxmIrtJiBlLkLhJJnWmSjceNsQnCaOFt36cStJKTHbRkydezuBJyIgvlQH-8Y3nTXLpIbo3JQjxTJ-lUwmY8bLnyxS91DaKEjmip3DoXJLSa4uOivuC68npCCtPVFeHbdHrzS_wQTRsUEh1o0XtWI1TtW868mV3njXwtjHdKxp7Uk8wfY5i5R4qJHxXWgf8PuXJA99Hh1Jwzee_tuA67wnPxvKf95mFkZVYZdDqNKrFkDE9B7-r5FjLi3pQZdTMXjFBGAMv20jrM5BuvCZLP9p6ugbG5pOBRUjBT5RtQpw48_th6pTa4W36MkBkh5TbXS27yuOXvi-b3blcSCEiizEDcJvqm4DBwqCNlSR8iG_QgktFDzkG99--LHV4R956K6cAozVAeyv0Jo9mKfaTsRLlMNhfTFpPrZmR5hVb11CEmmLi9C84aK1eivlYOZenzdZKpYE2mBKjZXOl96PJ3jb-OwEO2MDw9fyGzez8NaVhWAGGw9rm1iXnQyGljOw_ufOr5GLPHXXMhjSGVpXbN65sCTv8p6XGZnJiW7otVUzzmxG_kYQ3tkFLTyG9p6SG3GGBDVYG_pkDpPWavWlQdplIDTsOrjoXu-8sAYTx6GO_rGL13haW7KY9pRi9v3324zkNYOYL8CWWZzjcm26607lTEhpVWvkP4QwisGjvrAMoyj-GnlKvyK1u-1sPcuRMUg-8AKRYzBdtlChoUOtdVwYsOHxiLAkRMBH4PRIqWyUNILmlugXGNA7umZxj8uWy2mKjpZ7M8D_YlR66tj4duARp0lJYfeuvDqbXABVuSoLs8qaEFuYXLfiTNH4zItNeMQjfzT_eh9S_ligNALdOb82FgZzYv5ZKbFMo2s9kwzAb4PdwyaZjIP4_UJiJBqOazslWJYpdMLY2ZHGwfg0ZFP3adV06hbR1i9bJ7lyew2Dalqh9Sq-cFPg32-6rbZXYJnFFzfMks4FOJCgPOhCz2QODdbZU8_nQp_EQ4mIXnD2BR6BcCa3odD8rliM3IYOWnq3AhCHen55FwygCw6-u61Q03m4httHFozE-x4YiQivTQ70YUmdYNMyU_chQ3WfiJzaOgEwjq8vIP0hasxiaE1fBG7PncjGCUNB9sFiyVYjmSbP68iIQFqQ10oo9hnMYVxs_nSdem23fDNOutoikzjSHPo4_qxg-hNV0GDIrzBPLGsGw_W9agnUQOpwtpYycZ9v472FWhI5z0c8-8U7D9cV9s0ELyO9U7_vHhSoZJCq1edIFVVKTHsVfR2-vOlCHuqlbH4TzqGtIzf-5nUuY7HQ4iIxdjOrfU2GtMaU_tB8v3ZsC2Nr7IMYeyeBhItOXccNnqHUhMyZ-LdHkoafendmWTnnMOlkK2l91Jil4tPrJyVn1YFlsbzobQOurrsz2MAW3Ew1ibTCsRvlKWRs8dOSAxoUBcQL-r9g5_BcF0wsV7xzWvIHFm7fOuqLGsjsrCMAuXKImA2tFYECpr6vqCq8ORdqapUOlMb0_K4Iae-AhEkbMVERgLS3O05tRhQATMl2jnqA71DImzDoQMC_c45ELXToqX7x0oiINsOLQKBFQjiQ4-G9C1DJlZ67ZVtSN2PyKVNqMNegEtSz1uieOmkoXa1Vq62CrDp7KORToTHMZEV9uWe7KAOzqYm7jwhEvFs2jgvSga9Au2YgzqxbBjpC8RDSQqhUZTQeg2gecFLRpIObQ._YXzEw0gT4HbLqcFfdWoFQ")
                request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                request.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                request.addHeader("Cookie", "XMLHttpRequest")
                chain.proceed(request.build())
            }

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(
                WebServices::
                class.java
            )
        }
    }
```

and here is my error:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://pilot.wakecap.com/api/sites/10010001/workers
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=57KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=58KB, data=56KB
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized https://pilot.wakecap.com/api/sites/10010001/workers (2645ms)
D/OkHttp: Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2019 20:16:44 GMT
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 83
D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
D/OkHttp: X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
D/OkHttp: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
D/OkHttp: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
D/OkHttp: X-Download-Options: noopen
D/OkHttp: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
D/OkHttp: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
D/OkHttp: ETag: W/"53-ocmggiYI6s3nDDtb9FHiqlrJJYU"
D/OkHttp: {"code":"unauthenticated","message":"Server Error. Try again later!!","status":401}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (83-byte body)
```

PS: I have also used Cookies but it didn't help
PS2: it says try again later, but it works perfectly fine with Postman
PS3: For some reasons, Volley works just fine :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found out what was the problem.

The problem was I had to use "https" and I was using http, apparently Volley and Postman both automatically add the s in the end but Retrofit didn't for some reasons.